# Align multiple dataframes in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have these 4 spark dataframes:

```
order,device,count_1
101,201,2
102,202,4

order,device,count_2
101,201,10
103,203,100

order,device,count_3
104,204,111
103,203,10

order,device,count_4
101,201,4
104,204,11
```

I want to create a resultant dataframe as:

```
order,device,count_1,count_2,count_3,count_4
101,201,2,10,,4,
102,202,4,,,,
103,203,,100,10,,
104,204,,,111,11
```

Is this a case of `UNION or JOIN or APPEND`? How to get the final resultant df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
val df1 = Seq((101,201,2), (102,202,4)).toDF("order" ,"device", "count_1")
val df2 = Seq((101,201,10), (103,203,100)).toDF("order" ,"device", "count_2")
val df3 = Seq((104,204,111), (103,203,10)).toDF("order" ,"device", "count_3")
val df4 = Seq((101,201,4), (104,204,11)).toDF("order" ,"device", "count_4")

val df12 = df1.join(df2, Seq("order", "device"),"fullouter")
df12.show(false)
val df123 = df12.join(df3, Seq("order", "device"),"fullouter")
df123.show(false)
val df1234 = df123.join(df4, Seq("order", "device"),"fullouter")
df1234.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|order|device|count_1|count_2|count_3|count_4|
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|101  |201   |2      |10     |null   |4      |
|102  |202   |4      |null   |null   |null   |
|103  |203   |null   |100    |10     |null   |
|104  |204   |null   |null   |111    |11     |
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

As you can see the comments are flawed and the 1st answer incorrect.

#### Did in Scala, should be easy to do in pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `UNION` as combining tables by **rows**, so the number of rows will likely increase. `JOIN` combines tables by **columns**. I'm not sure what you mean by `APPEND`, but in this case, you would want `JOIN`.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` to be precise (default is `INNER JOIN`)